# MultiThreading in Bash Script

Tags: bash

i run php from bash, and looping as much line in text file.

this is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
cat data.txt | while read line
do
   echo 'scrape: '$line
   php index.php $line >> output.csv
done
```

how i can run Simultaneously, say 10 thread per run.

Comment: bash doesn't really have threads, but you can run processes in the background by putting `&` at the end of the line, or you could look at a tool like [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

Comment: You're really pushing the limits of bash. You would have a *much* easier time using a proper scripting language like python or ruby for this

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with `sem` from GNU parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat data.txt | while read line
do
   echo 'scrape: '$line
   sem -j 10 php index.php $line >> output.csv
done
```

However, it's up to you to ensure that the output makes sense when written in parallel to the same file. You may want to write to different files and join them afterwards.

Comment: Change `output.csv` to something like`output$((i++)).csv`

Answer (score 1):

While that other guy's answer is correct, `sem` is quite slow (300 ms per job), and can in this case it can be replaced by a single call to GNU Parallel (which takes around 300 ms in startup and 10 ms per job):

```
parallel -j10 "echo scrape: {}; php index.php {}" :::: data.txt > output.csv
```

For one file per job:

```
parallel -j10 "(echo scrape: {}; php index.php {}) > output{#}.csv" :::: data.txt
```